# How to log in with sha256 in CakePHP 3?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-3.0, password-hash

I have a problem. I did a login form with all by default (bcrypt), but I need to do it with sha256 password in my database. How can I do it?
This is my AppController:

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'nombre',
                    'passwordHasher' => array( 
                        'hashType' => 'sha256',
                        'className' => 'password'
                    )
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Home',
            'action' => 'index'
        ]
    ]);
    // Allow the display action so our pages controller
    // continues to work.
    $this->Auth->allow(['display']);
}
```

And usersController:

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error('El usuario o contraseña no es válido.');
    }
}
```

I have to say that no errors are showed, but it shows that user or password are incorrect.

Comment: 'className' => 'password'? How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: Hi, is whar the official book says but I don't really know what to put.

Comment: Where does it say that? It would never do that afaik.